# Driver win32k.sys marked pagable instead of nonpagable

Tags: windows-vista, drivers, bsod

A friend has the following BSOD on Vista, about each 45 minutes:

> A problem has been detected and Windows has been shut down to prevent
>   damage to your computer.
>
> > `win32k.sys`
>
> The driver mistakenly marked a part of it's image pagable instead of
>   nonpagable.
>
> [...]
>
> Technical information:
>
> ```
> *** STOP: 0x000000D3 [...]
>
> win32k.sys
> ```

[image: Image of the BSOD]

It has been that way for a few weeks, and there was no change or new install, except for a Windows Update. Moreover, he has reinstalled Windows a few weeks ago.

What is the cause/solution to that symptom?

Comment: update the graphic card driver and look if this fixes it.

Comment: @magicandre1981: exactly what I told him, we're waiting for results ;)